# about Last name

Tags: passport

My name is Geetha. I don't have last name in any of my records (i.e Marks Cards, DL, Adhar card, voter id). Now I work for a company and they are asking for Last name which I don't have. Any how I added my dad's name but they are asking for proof which I don't have. Is there any way to add last name where I can hold some proof shows my name? I'm facing a lot of issues without a last name.

Comment: You haven't told us any of the important information: Where are you? Where are you from? What is your legal status where you are currently living?

Comment: Does your birth certificate show your father's name?

Comment: @flimzy aadhar is the indian national identity system and marks card means college transcript.  hi geetha, depending on how much trouble this causes you, you might want to legally change your name in india.  google "how to change your name in india" for directions.  one option might be applying for a *passport* and asking for that document to include your father's name, which the government might be able to do without a formal name change.